# Proving that a sequence of functions has a convergent subsequence

Tags: functional-analysis, sequence-of-function

Let $X$ be a metric space and $(f_n)$ an equicontinuous sequence of functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$.
We suppose that $A=\{x\in X| \{f_n(x),n=1,2,...\} \text{ is bounded}\}$, is not empty, and that $X$ is compact and connected.

I have to prove that $(f_n)$ has a convergent subsequence.

I have proved in a previous question that the set $A$ is both open and closed, so since $X$ is connected and $A$ is nonempty we'll have $A=X$. But I don't know how to use this to construct a convergent subsequence.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Your definition of $A$ is unclear.  I suspect the phrase $x \in X$ doesn't belong there.

Comment: @RobertShore : $A$ is the set of elements $x$ of $X$ such that the set $\{f_n(x),n=1,2,...\}$ is bounded.

Comment: You should read about the Arzelà-Ascoli theorem.

Comment: My intuition says that the compactness of $X$ will imply that, if $(f_n)$ doesn't have a convergent subsequence then there exists $x\in X$ such that $\{f_n(x),n=1,...\}$ is unbounded.

Comment: @AndréPorto : we can use the compactness of $X$ to prove that $(f_n)$ is uniformly bounded and then apply Arzelà-Ascoli theorem as suggested by cmk.

Answer (score 1):

I think I was able to prove that by using Arzelà-Ascoli theorem as suggested by cmk in the comments.
To apply this theorem, we just need to prove that $(f_n)$ is uniformly bounded.
$(f_n)$ is equicontinuous so $\forall x\in X$ there is an open neighborhood $V_x$ of $x$ such that $\forall n\ge 1\ \forall t\in V_x\ |f_n(t)-f_n(x)|<1$
$X=\bigcup V_x$ and $X$ is compact so $\exists x_1,x_2,...,x_p\in X$ such that $X=V_{x_1}\cup...\cup V_{x_p}$.
$(f_n(x_i))$ is bounded so $\exists M_i>0$ such that $|f_n(x_i)|<M_i\ \forall n$.
$\forall t\in V_{x_i}\ \forall n\ |f_n(t)|\le |f_n(x_i)|+|f_n(x_i)-f_n(t)|<M_i+1\le M$
where $M=max(M_1,...,M_p)+1$.  So $(f_n)$ is uniformly bounded and by Arzelà-Ascoli's theorem we can extract a convergent subsequence.